# pipe stdout-to-file with wc

Tags: shell, pipe, stdout, tcsh

I'm working on a lab assignment for a class, which exemplifies `users | wc -w` as displaying the number of users currently logged in. The instructor has asked we write the output of `users` to a file (`users > file`), while still displaying the count. My initial thought was to change the original example to simply read `users > file | wc -w`, but I receive the error:

```
ambiguous output redirect
```

Our college's Unix lab has us working, by default in `tcsh`, and I know the commands can differ between the shells. Is there a command that can accomplish this that I'm completely forgetting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tee`:

```
users | tee file | wc -w
```

Gives as output the number of users, and it writes a file with the users as content.

---

**The case in your question**:

```
command >file | command2
```

This cannot work. With `>file` you redirect the ouput of `command` to the file `file` and in the same the output is written to an anonymous pipe, where the command `command2` reads at the other end. This is an ambiguous redirection.

The `tee` command will accept a `file` as argument, in which `tee` writes everything it recieves from its standard input. `tee` also writes everything from standard input to its standard output, where you can redirect to further commands or files.

Comment: It's perhaps useful to mention that the name "tee" is named after a T-splitter, which is exactly what the commands does: take some input, and "split" it to both stdout and a file; you can then further pipe stdout to other processes ([wikipedia has a nice image of this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tee.svg)).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Good image, that's the `T`, didn't know that. BTW: the manpage of `tee` is also very concise: `tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files`

Comment: Okay, thanks! I had visited the `man` page for tee, but it sort of threw me off, I wasn't sure that was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command to accomplish this; it's called `tee`:

```
users | tee file | wc -w
```

PS.
(External) commands do not differ between shells; input and output redirection syntax does vary.